# KnockoutJS access active item created via activator forItems

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

As per the Master-detail samples, such as [this](https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-2.0/blob/gh-pages/app/masterDetail/dFiddle/index.js), but with factory pattern for viewmodels:

`this.activateProduct = activator.create().forItems(this.products);`

```
<div data-bind="foreach: products">
   <a data-bind="click: $parent.activateProduct">click activates</a>`
</div>
```

Debugging `<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(activateProduct, null, 2)"></pre>` outputs the model and it's data.

However `<div data-bind="text: activateProduct.name"></div>` returns nothing, tried unwrapping, calling as valueAssessor function etc and can't find the observables which `ko.toJSON` has somehow found.

Does this all have to be broken down into separate steps using `activateItem` while storing the "current item"?

Any syntax which will retrieve the observables inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

`ko.unwrap(activateProduct).name()`

Problem is that `ko.unwrap(activateProduct) == null` until it is activated by the click. Thus setting it simply to that will result in a binding error.

```
Unable to process binding "text: function (){return ko.unwrap(activateProduct).name() }"
Message: ko.unwrap(...) is null;
```

Thus you must first check for a null value for the activator before attempting to bind it's observables.

```
<div data-bind="text: (ko.unwrap(activateProduct) !== null) ? ko.unwrap(activateProduct).name():''"></div>
```

Comment: just to clarify:
if you used `text: activateProduct().name` it would lock you into a static version of the product and wouldn't change when you changed the `activateProduct` observable value right?

Comment: It seemed not... The first time through the bindings there is no activator assigned to the variable so at that stage it would error "not a function". Then when the binding does come along it doesn't know to refresh the display with new data (as the binding failed). You could probably skip the `ko.unwrap` though and just check for the function being there... Maybe if I assigned something to it early in the constructor and bound that instead of waiting for the activator to define `activateProduct` (or bound a proxy function that then has the activator inside, maybe).

Comment: what about a `with` binding?

Comment: That might well work too... Although activeProduct itself is null at the start, so I'm not certain it would then display when updated.

Comment: `with` binding does update when something change from null to an object.